# Linux script not running on start up

Tags: ubuntu, scripting, startup

Hello and thank you for being so helpful. I am trying to run a script at startup that reduces the power limits of my gpus. The shell command is in init.d and I have tried using symlink to rc1 and rc3. The shell command has also been made executable using Chmod +x. I am running Ubuntu 16.04 as well. When I restart the computer only 1 card drops the wattage to the appropriate level while the other two stay unchanged. This is gpu0. Any help would be much appreciated. I have also tried using Crontab and have had difficulties. My script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "Run as sudo to lower power-limits."
echo ""

nvidia-smi -i 0 -pl 100
nvidia-smi -i 1 -pl 100
nvidia-smi -i 2 -pl 100

echo ""
echo ""

nvidia-smi
```

Comment: You need the full path of the command when in crontab; that is a regular one here. As for boot time, Ubuntu 16.04 uses not UpStart but systemd.

Comment: I’ve used the full path in crontab. I did notice some cron folders under /etc/ must they be there? I was using @reboot /Desktop/reduce-power-limit.sh/

Comment: I have also tried placing the shell command in cron.d and get the same issue

Comment: Put a call to your script in `/etc/rc.local` and use the full path to commands.  Also, does it work if you run it manually after boot & login ?

Comment: Have you tried starting the script from the console? Bash isn't installed by default on Ubuntu, the shebang should be `#!/bin/sh`.

Comment: I do not have  an rc.local folder. I will try adjusting the she bang

Comment: Adjusting the shebang has the same outcome. The first card changes wattage and the remaining 2 do nothing. Gpu0 is at 100 and gpu1 & gpu2 are at 151

Comment: Also this script runs fine if I run it manually from terminal manually

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put the full path (where this script is actually located) in `rc.local`. Whatever you put in `rc.local` will run like root user while the OS is ready to execute the script (plaese, forgive the lack of exactitude and for my english), so be carefull. 
I leave you an example:

```
nano /etc/rc.local
#!/bin/sh -e
#
# rc.local
#
# This script is executed at the end of each multiuser runlevel.
# Make sure that the script will "exit 0" on success or any other
# value on error.
#
# In order to enable or disable this script just change the execution
# bits.
#
# By default this script does nothing.

/usr/local/samba/bin/samba_dnsupdate --use-samba-tool
exit 0
```

This means that when my OS is ready to run scripts it will run `samba_dnsupdate` with the option `--use-samba-tool`, and this script is actually in `/usr/local/samba/sbin/`

Greetings

Comment: I do not have an rc.local folder I have rc1-6.d and rcS.d

Comment: I have found the rc.local file. How would I run the script in this file

Comment: I have added /etc/bin/reduce-power-limit.sh to the rc.local file. Is there anything else I need to do? It’s still not working.

Comment: I put the wrong path in rc.local. It works!!!!! Thank you so so so much

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, I'm in Cuba and I only have internet in my work... so if it work for you then congratulations!!! Any question feel free to ask here :-)