# Run Python script along with OS boot

Tags: linux, fedora, live-usb, runlevel

I'm booting my system with a custom `Fedora 27 Workstation` live OS which is containing a python script apart from the regular OS files. I want this `enable_settings.py` scripts to be executed along with my OS boot.

So, where should I keep this file in my ISO image and what changes do I need to make to run it by default.

Note:

- I don't want to run this script on the second run, I want to run it in the very first boot. So, these changes need to be done on ISO image only.
- By default, live OS is booting in `run-level 5`

Comment: Please, see if [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/421662/linux-script-not-running-on-start-up/421688#421688) can help you.

(Possible duplicated subject)

Comment: @Cyborg It's not working because after OS boot, `rc.local` file is not present in the `/etc/` directory as this is live OS.

Comment: Sorry, I don't know how to help you.

Comment: I've got a way to do this, by making a custom `systemd-service` which will run your script. Anyway, thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, could you point (links?) me how you do what you do?